# Способ парсинга сайта для Python

Tags: python, парсер

Меня интересует быстрый и легкий способ получения быстро обновляющегося текста (1 сек), по сути весь этот текст состоит из 3-х символов. Все дело происходит на веб странице, к нужному элементу можно обратиться через DevTools.

Я не хочу использовать Selenium, потому что, по мне он достаточно медленный, а также при моих попытках искать объект хоть с XPath, хоть по CSS селектору, слишком часто возвращались ошибки.

Я знаю о таких вариантах, как lxml, BeatifulSoup, но еще не работал с ними, поэтому не знаю, с чего начать.

Возможен ли такой вариант: в самой консоли DevTools написать Java скрипт, который будит выводить нужные мне данные (текст) в отдельный файл текстового редактора и делать это быстро и многократно? А из блокнота его можно легко вывести в Питон.

Comment: В DevTools нужно проанализировать куда и какого рода вопросы делаются. Скорее всего там ajax-запросы json-данных. После чего можно просто повторить их с помощью библиотеки requests.